# Cherry-picking one JSON object to create multiple arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary

I have a JSON array with thirty objects (the last 30 days including today). Each object has these properties:

```
{
    "date": "2013-05-20",
    "notCachedRequestsDevelopment": "115482",
    "cachedRequestsDevelopment": "4732914",
    "notCachedBandwidthDevelopment": "15525231867",
    "cachedBandwidthDevelopment": "2571078929",
    "rejectRequestsDevelopment": "44068",
    "rejectBandwidthDevelopment": "23169212",
    "nonCSSCachedRequestsDevelopment": "6789",
    "nonCSSNotCachedRequestsDevelopment": "1440",
    "notCachedRequestsProduction": "9",
    "cachedRequestsProduction": "1089270",
    "notCachedBandwidthProduction": "2186497",
    "cachedBandwidthProduction": "616508357",
    "rejectRequestsProduction": "359",
    "rejectBandwidthProduction": "168977",
    "nonCSSCachedRequestsProduction": "0",
    "CDNCachedRequests": 6062986,
    "CDNNotCachedRequests": "272901.0",
    "CDNRejectRequests": "84764.0",
    "CDNAllBandwidth": 56006050473.574,
    "billingBandwidth": 22525362831.36,
    "billingHits": 6489103
}
```

I need to take this JSON and create a few new Arrays. For example:

I need one new array called `totalBandwidth` that takes each JSON object and tallies the following properties: `notCachedBandwidthDevelopment + cachedBandwidthDevelopment + rejectBandwidthDevelopment + notCachedBandwidthProduction + cachedBandwidthProduction + rejectBandwidthProduction`

I need another array that called `developmentBandwidth` and gets the following sum from each object: `cachedBandwidthDevelopment + notCachedBandwidthDevelopment`

… and so on.

I can do this with a `for` loop for each new array, but I suspect there is a smarter way about this?

Comment: How can array tally something? Are you wanting a number that is the sum of many numbers? Or an array of numbers?

Comment: I just mean to say the values for each array item will be the result of summing properties from the JSON object. Make sense?

Comment: I don't know why you think there's a smarter way? Why don't you like the one you currently are using?

Comment: Why are some of your values numbers and others are strings? Do you want to concatenate them, or sum them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1: Array.prototype.map()

You can try out the new javascript `Array.prototype.map()` array function. In your case, you might want something like:

```
var developmentBandwidth = origArray.map(function(obj) {
  return parseInt(obj.cachedBandwidthDevelopment) + parseInt(obj.notCachedBandwidthDevelopment);
});
```

`developmentBandwidth` will be an array of numbers.

Note that this is only implemented in ECMAScript 5, and only available in modern browsers. Check out MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

They provide a compatibility function that allows you to use the function on older browsers.

---

### Option 2: jQuery.map()

Looks like the jQuery library provides a similar function. The same example above can be achieved by:

```
var developmentBandwidth = $.map(origArray, function(obj, index) {
  return parseInt(obj.cachedBandwidthDevelopment) + parseInt(obj.notCachedBandwidthDevelopment);
});
```

---

Look [here](http://jsperf.com/jquery-map-vs-array-map) for a comparison between the two options

Comment: Doesn't jQuery have an implementation of this, too?

Comment: Looks like they do indeed! http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/ I was not aware of that.

Comment: Ended up using this. Thanks! `var developmentBandwidth = $.map(data, function(item) {
 return item.cachedBandwidthDevelopment + item.notCachedBandwidthDevelopment;
});`

Answer (score 1):

In case you're looking to eliminate duplication further, here's a coffeescript solution, using shorter variable names to ease readability (see [this link](http://coffeescript.org/#try%3ademoFunction%20%3D%20%28daysdata%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20result%20%3D%20%7B%7D%0A%20%20totalsNeeded%20%3D%20%7Bfoo%3A%20%5B%27a%27%2C%20%27b%27%5D%2C%20bar%3A%20%5B%27b%27%2C%27c%27%5D%7D%0A%20%20sumFields%20%3D%20%28fields%2C%20obj%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20sum%20%3D%20%28t%2Cs%29%20-%3E%20t%2Bobj%5Bs%5D%0A%20%20%20%20fields.reduce%28sum%2C0%29%0A%20%20buildDaysArray%20%3D%20%28fields%29%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20sumFields%28fields%2Cdata%29%20for%20data%20in%20daysData%0A%20%20for%20name%2C%20fields%20of%20totalsNeeded%0A%20%20%20%20result%5Bname%5D%20%3D%20buildDaysArray%28fields%29%0A%20%20result%0A%0A%0Aday1%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%201%2C%20b%3A%202%2C%20c%3A%203%7D%0Aday2%20%3D%20%7Ba%3A%204%2C%20b%3A%205%2C%20c%3A%206%7D%0Aalert%28JSON.stringify%28demoFunction%28%5Bday1%2C%20day2%5D%29%29%29%0A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%0A%0A) for equivalent javascript):

```
demoFunction = (daysdata) ->
  result = {}
  totalsNeeded = {foo: ['a', 'b'], bar: ['b','c']}
  sumFields = (fields, obj) ->
    sum = (t,s) -> t+obj[s]
    fields.reduce(sum,0)
  buildDaysArray = (fields) ->
    sumFields(fields,data) for data in daysData
  for name, fields of totalsNeeded
    result[name] = buildDaysArray(fields)
  result


day1 = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3}
day2 = {a: 4, b: 5, c: 6}
alert(JSON.stringify(demoFunction([day1, day2]))) # => {"foo":[3,9],"bar":[5,11]}
```